# Magento2 - TinyMCE editor adds %20 in image url

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wysiwyg, tinymce

The TinyMce editor adds %20 before the image url.

Expected output

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/pdf/pdf.png"}}" /></p>
```

Output

```
<p><img src="%20%20%20%20{{media url="wysiwyg/pdf/pdf.png"}}" /></p>
```

I've tried adding `rep(/%20/gi,"");` in `lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/bbcode/editor_plugin_src.js:87`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Nope... Still facing the same issue

Comment: I found the solution, 
Change your `lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/js/image.js` line 145
to
`src: nl.src.value.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20'),`
so it will trim the white space from left and right of the string.
please note that if you update it this fix will be overridden, so I still looking for a proper override method.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution for this, 
Change your

> lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/js/image.js

line 145

to

> src: nl.src.value.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20'),

so it will trim the white space from left and right of the string.

*Please note that if you update, this fix will be overridden, 
so I still looking for a proper override method.*